# Get token by gapi

Tags: google-api, token, passport.js, google-oauth

I followed [this link](http://www.codexworld.com/login-with-google-account-using-javascript/) and made a test page of google login by `gapi`. It worked, and did return the profile details.

Previously, I had tried [this appraoch by passport.js](https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-google), but because of the [fragment problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43060377/work-around-for-fragment-urls-not-allowed-with-google-redirect-uri), I did not manage to make it work.

In the `passportjs` appraoch, we could get a `token`. Does anyone know how we could get a `token` by `gapi`?

Additionally, does anyone know why we don't need to specify a secret in the code of `gapi`?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the token in the [AuthResponse](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#googleusergetauthresponseincludeauthorizationdata).

You do need an API key for gapi too:

```
gapi.client.init({
  'apiKey': 'YOUR_API_KEY',
  ...
})
```

Comment: Sorry, the `apiKey` refers to the `client id` or the `secret`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34804016/googleuser-getauthresponse-doesnt-contain-access-token